# Does “very” have two meanings?

Tags: adjective-degrees

1. It’s very rainy.

It means it rains a lot.

2. The sun is very bright.

It means the sun makes intense light.

In conclusion, “very” means either “very large in amount” or “very large in degree.”

What I wonder is this. Can “toxic,” for example, mean both “having much poison” and “having intense poison”?

Comment: A dictionary is all you need to answer this question. If in doubt, consult several.

Comment: @Ronald Sole But “very toxic” is usually used not as “having much poison” unlike “very rainy.” I wonder about this.

Comment: Very means the same thing whether used before rainy or toxic.

Comment: I edited that answer if you checked before. Better now

Comment: It’s very dark. = It is **DARK**!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those two very’s have the same meaning.

“Very” does not add any meaning of its own. “Very” only means, “Increase the adjective!”

“Increase the adjective by the adjective’s own meaning. Make it more that way.”

Very: Make it more rainy. Make it more bright.

How rainy is it? This depends on the amount of rain. So “very” increases the amount.

How bright is the sun? This depends on the intensity of the sun. So “very” increases the intensity. It means “underline the following adjective.”